# Mongodb - connect through ODBC

Tags: mongodb, connection, odbc, driver

I am trying to achieve a connection to MongoDB server using the delivered ODBC Driver from MongoDB installed by windows client side. When I fill in the DSN properties it freeze on Test button hit.

I tried then to follow that procedure by installing the MongoDB BI Connector by client side and declaring the mongodbsqld service but didn't help.

https://www.sqlshack.com/import-data-from-mongodb-to-sql-server-using-ssis/

I have the Free MongoDB Community version
Mongodb shell version - 4.0.11
Mongodb server version - 4.0.20
ODBC Driver: 1.4.2

I tried a commercial driver developed by Progress, it works like a charm but expire in few days.
Do you have some tips to establish this ODBC connection properly ?

Thanks & Regards,
Manu

Comment: Please include code or images of what you are doing to add clarity so the community can help you.

Answer (score 5):

The open [MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-driver-for-the-mongodb-connector-for-business-intelligence) works only with MongoDB Cloud service:

> The BI Connector is only available on Atlas M10 instances and above.

I guess you have to go for a third party driver.

Apart from [Progress](https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb) I found also

- CData: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/
- devart: https://www.devart.com/odbc/mongodb/
- EasySoft: https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver/index.html
- Simba: https://www.simba.com/drivers/mongodb-odbc-jdbc/

But none of them is for free, you have to spend some money I guess.

**Update:**

Meanwhile I managed it to use the [MongoDB BI Connector ODBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/reference/odbc-driver/).

First you need to download and install the [MongoDB Connector for BI](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/installation/). Once BI Connector is up and running you can use the MongoDB ODBC Driver and create the ODBC DNS according to your needs.

However, I tested it only for read operations - which should be the main purpose anyway.

Comment: Hi Wernfried, this is exactly what I supposed...thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for read only operations like select or all CRUD operations?
If read only, you can install and run mongosqld on mongodb instance, and then connect with mysql/mariadb driver just like a mysql connection.

If you need write access, you have to use 3rd-party drivers as of now.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No, mongosqld works for the self hosted mongo community version too.