# Can I execute atomic transactions with MongoDB from R?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, mongolite, rmongo

As the title states: Is there a way with any of the mongodb-clients in R to execute atomic transactions? If so, how would I do this? I couldn't find any documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use `DBI` that package allows for transactions (`dbBegin`, `dbCommit` usw). It seems you can make a connection with `odbc`: https://db.rstudio.com/databases/mongodb/ . I have not tested this but it seems it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I'm not using RStudio Professional, it seems that I would need to install one of the third-party ODBC drivers listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66122921/1003358. So the workflow would be: install the driver --> register in `odbcinst.ini` --> use `DBI` with `odbc` as shown in the link you've provided. Is this right? And it seems that there is no way to do this for free and without hassle (like normal operations via e.g. `mongolite`)?

Comment: I have no experience with mongodb nor with `mongolite` so I dont know any more details. a quick scan over `mongolite` seems to not show support for transactions