# Can I connect a mongoDB compass database to power bi?

Tags: mongodb, powerbi-desktop

My organisation has an application that uses mongodb compass to store its data , and I wanted to export that data to power bi to create visualized reports from the data , is this possible  from mongodb compass?

I tried different connectors but everything seems to only work for mongodb atlas

Comment: In regards to terminology - "MongoDB Compass" is not a place to store data. MongoDB is the database, Compass is a GUI client for interacting with or exploring the database

Comment: Yes, it is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122411/mongodb-connect-through-odbc/66122921#66122921

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Compass is a front-end to the MongoDB database.  The Compass tool is a database client, not the database itself.  PowerBI is a Microsoft reporting tool, which is also a front-end to the database.  PowerBI expects data to be tabular, not rich nested data which MongoDB supports.  To provide compatability, MongoDB has created the BI Connector, which is a man-in-the-middle conversion adapter that allows the rich structured data to be emulated as tabular data to be compatible with tools such as PowerBI.  See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/.  It's worth noting, if you are using MongoDB Atlas, you could instead use the new Atlas SQL Interface, which is the next generation BI Connectivity offering by MongoDB.  See https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/sql.