# Connect and manage remote MongoDB using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, mongodb, odbc

I cannot seem to figure out whether it is possible to manage my remote Mongo database using Excel VBA code. I'd love to be able to do what I'm able to do with Node.js, namely, connect, find, replace, insert documents and so on.
I hear that I have to have MongoDB ODBC driver installed, and I've done it, but what's next? I can't even find it on my Tools > References list.

Comment: Which driver did you install? Note, I think (but I am not 100% sure) you can use the Mongo ODBC driver only to query the database but not for update or inserts. You can manage your MongoDB also with specific tools like Compass, Studio3T or similar.

Comment: I installed MongoDB ODBC from the official website. I have Compass, but I'm looking for a way to send my Excel data directly to mongodb and manage the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "manage the database "?

Comment: Pls. check this site [Connect From Microsoft Excel](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/connect/excel/)

Comment: I mean that I would like to have a way to programmatically query a database, find documents, insert documents, delete documents. All of that using Excel VBA.

Comment: Thank you, Black Cat. But my question is rather how I get my data from Excel and to MongoDB, while the page you suggested talks about the reverse.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information. What means "I have installed the Mongo ODBC driver"?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what exactly you are looking for, thus I can give only generic answer. Be aware Excel/VBA/COM is maybe 40 years old, MongoDB is a modern tool. Below a few possibilities:

#### MongoDB Connector for BI / ODBC Driver

First of all, with the [MongoDB Connector for BI](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/master/what-is-the-bi-connector/) you can only **query** the data from MongoDB, it does not provide any inserts or updates.

The *MongoDB Connector for BI* is a service which connects to a MongoDB and translates the BSON documents into SQL/Table style data. Then you must install the [MongoDB BI Connector ODBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/reference/odbc-driver/). Be aware to install ODBC driver having the same architecture (i.e. 32-Bit vs. 64-Bit) as your Excel. When this is installed, you will see it in the ODBC Administrator Drivers:

[image]

The next step is to create a DSN for your connection. There you enter the data source (which is the server and port from above MongoDB Connector for BI) and credentials. Then you can use the DSN in tools like Excel.

#### 3rd party ODBC drivers

Have a look at [Mongodb - connect through ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122411/mongodb-connect-through-odbc/66122921#66122921)

Most of them are easier to install, because they connect directly to your MongoDB, instead of using an intermediate service like the *MongoDB Connector for BI*. Some of them even support inserting or updating the data in your MongoDB. However, all these drivers are not for free.

#### Bridge in .NET/C#

You could write an assembly (i.e. a DLL) in .NET, for example C# and use the [MongoDB C# Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/). When you make the assembly "COM visible", you can use the DLL in your VBA Macro. But depending on your requirements it will be a lot of code you have to write.

#### MongoDB Database tools

Another option could be to create a CSV file from your Excel. Then call  [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) (using [Shell()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function)) to import the CSV File into your MongoDB. With `mongoexport` you can do the other way around, i.e. from MongoDB into Excel. Instead of a file, you can also read and write to/from STDIN/STDOUT.

However, you can only import or export the data, you hardly can query or update anything. Instead of `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` you can pass your data also to the Mongo Shell `mongosh`. There you would have more flexibility.

#### MongoDB IDE

Anyway, my personal suggestion would be: forget about Excel and VBA and use a proper MongoDB IDE, for example Compass, Studio3T or DBeaver. They are all available for free.